# Ruby on Rails - Truncate to a specific string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Clarification:** The creator of the post should be able to decide when the truncation should happen.

I implemented a Wordpress like [---MORE---] functionality in my blog with following helper function:

```
# application_helper.rb

def more_split(content)
split = content.split("[---MORE---]")
split.first
end

def remove_more_tag(content)
content.sub(“[---MORE---]", '')
end
```

In the index view the post body will display everything up to (but without) the [---MORE---] tag.

```
# index.html.erb
<%= raw more_split(post.rendered_body) %>
```

And in the show view everything from the post body will be displayed except the [---MORE---] tag.

```
# show.html.erb
<%=raw remove_more_tag(@post.rendered_body) %>
```

This solution currently works for me without any problems.
Since I am still a beginner in programming I am constantly wondering if there is **a more elegant way to accomplish this**.

How would you do this?

Thanks for your time.

---

**This is the updated version:**

```
# index.html.erb
<%=raw truncate(post.rendered_body,  
                :length => 0, 
                :separator => '[---MORE---]', 
                :omission => link_to( "Continued...",post)) %>
```

...and in the show view:

```
# show.html.erb
<%=raw (@post.rendered_body).gsub("[---MORE---]", '') %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use just simply truncate, it has all of the options you need.

```
truncate("And they found that many people were sleeping better.", :length => 25, :omission => '... (continued)')
# => "And they f... (continued)"
```

**Update**

After sawing the comments, and digging a bit the documentation it seems that the `:separator` does the work.

From the doc:

```
Pass a :separator to truncate text at a natural break.
```

For referenece see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)

```
truncate(post.rendered_body, :separator => '[---MORE---]')
```

On the show page you have to use `gsub`

Comment: Yes, I used that method before. But what if you want the user to decide when the truncate should happen?

Comment: truncate(post.rendered_body, :separator => '[---MORE---]')

Comment: This only seems to work if you define the length with it: truncate(post.rendered_body, `:separator => '[---MORE---]',:length => 0)`

Comment: I updated the initial question with the code that worked now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function on the index page that only grabs the first X characters in your string. So, it would look more like:

```
<%= raw summarize(post.rendered_body, 250) %>
```

to get the first 250 characters in your post. So, then you don't have to deal w/ splitting on the [---MORE---] string. And, on the show page for your post, you won't need to do anything at all... just render the `post.body`.

---

Here's an example summarize helper (that you would put in application_helper.rb):

```
def summarize(body, length)
return simple_format(truncate(body.gsub(/<\/?.*?>/,  ""), :length => length)).gsub(/<\/?.*?>/,  "")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found this one is the best and easiest

```
def summarize(body, length)
    return simple_format = body[0..length]+'...'
end

s = summarize("to get the first n characters in your post. So, then you don't have to deal w/ splitting on the [---MORE---]  post.body.",20)


ruby-1.9.2-p290 :017 > s
=> "to get the first n ..."
```